# How to allow access to subset of API only when connected via my official frontend, using Nest.js?

Tags: api, authentication, nestjs

I'm starting a Nest.js API, and a subset of my API is business critical. I don't want it accessible openly via HTTP(S), except if the request is coming from my website. Other APIs might instead by accessible with whatever third-party client.

Is there a way to achieve this using Nest.js?

Comment: You'd probably want to lock it behind a combination of authentication via https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication and some authorization mechanism.  Assign a role or permissions to the users you want to be able to make those requests and return a `403 Forbidden` to all other users who do not have those grants.

Comment: Hi @DylanAspden, thanks for your comment. This is not about logged in users. I want all logged in users **who are using the API from my app hosted at example.com** to have full access, but other users who are using `curl` or some other scraping mechanism to not have access to certain entities of the API.

Comment: AFAIK other than that there isn’t too much you could do except maybe setup CORS. You could also use CSRF tokens as a workaround. There’s no nest specific thing to address this that I’m aware of.